# Is it possible to compare configurations of two different IISs via sort of a IIS config file?

Tags: .net, iis

What I want to achieve is to compare IIS set ups of TESTING and STAGING environments.

Is it possible to export a sort-of configuration file from an IIS that would represent all the set-up details and use it to compare with another set-up details of an IIS that sits on different environment?

Answer (score 0):

One method, not particularly fun, is to go into IIS Manager, Choose the server in the connections tree on the left, then in the actions menu on the right choose "Export Server Package..." this will produce a zip file that is a comprehensive backup of the server/site/settings, so it may be a large file.

Do that for both servers, and then you can use a DIFF tool like [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) to compare the output of both.

Or in particular you will find most of the config data in the root of the zip archive of the export (**archive.xml** and **systeminfo.xml**) so start by looking at and comparing those.